# How would one simulate a charging experience on a real android device?

Tags: samsung, battery, charging, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I possess a Samsung Galaxy S8 with Samsung Global Goals installed. The app allows you to donate based on ads viewed during the time the device is charging. Would be possible to essentially 'fake' the charging experience to donate more on the go while also conserving energy? Morally questionable methods for the greater good are perfectly welcome ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unethical & not a fit for this site

Comment: Uh it is quite literally charity and just an intellectual endeavor. I'm not actually promoting any immoral practices.